# How do I present UIViewController from SKscene with social framework?

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, flappy-bird-clone, skscene

I am making a game like Flappy Bird. How do I present a UIViewController from SKScene?
First of all, I tell my environments

- Mac OS X 10.9
- Xcode 5.0.2
- Sprite Kit(framework), social.framework(framework) are added in my project

My goal is to display a "Share" button upon Game Over. Tapping the share button image should present a SLComposeViewController (Twitter Share). The contents of the scene should not change.
I'd like to solve bellow issue and change display from GameOverScene to tweetSheet(display)
composed with social.framework.

The issue

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
//Error:No visible @interface for 'GameOverScene' declares the selector "presentViewController":animated:completion:
```

My coding files are below(I extracted parts of important codes).

ViewController.h

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate><br>

@end
```

GameOverScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h> 

@class SpriteViewController;

@interface GameOverScene : SKScene {
}
@end
```

GameOverScene.m

```
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import "MainScene.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
@implementation GameOverScene {
   //The twitter button 
    SKSpriteNode *_twitterbutton;
}
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        //Creating the twitterbutton with the twitterbutton image from Images.xcassets
        _twitterbutton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"twitterbutton"];
        [_twitterbutton setSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        [_twitterbutton setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/5 + 50)];
        //Adding the twitter button
        [self addChild:_twitterbutton];
        //Again, this is important, otherwise we can't identify what button is pressed
        _twitterbutton.name = @"twitterbutton";
        [_twitterbutton setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/5 + 50)]
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Same as in NewGameScene menu
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    //Is the twitter button touched?
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"twitterbutton"]){
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]){
            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"TestTweet from the Game !!"];
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
     **//Error:No visible @interface for 'GameOverScene' declares the selector "presentViewController":animated:completion:**
         } 
    }
```

ViewControlloer.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
@implementation ViewController
//Loads the view onto our main class
- (void)loadView
{
  self.view  = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
}
//Executes when view finishes loading
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //Set the resize mode to flexible width and height
  [self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

  //Create our view from our original view
  //Make sure to leave originalContentView in, otherwise the app will crash
  SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;

  //We create a new NewGameScene according to the current dimensions
  SKScene *scene = [NewGameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

  //Create a transition class with animation type fade and a duration of .4 seconds
  SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.4];

  //Present the menu view (NewGameScene) with our fade in transition
  [skView presentScene:scene transition:transition];
}

@end
```

Comment: There's a lot of code pasted here, I doubt anyone's going to read all this. Read this guide about how to best present your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The process helps yourself understanding it better as well.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438719/how-do-i-present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438719/how-do-i-present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene

Comment: >>Henrik Thank you for the advice !! It's my first time to submit my question. If you feel angry, I am so sorry about that. I will use your helpful advice, thank you very much, sir.                                >>Theis Thank you for the advise. I am a beginner of Xcode, though. I knew the article and read more and more, but I couldn't understand, though... So, I submitted this question. What should I do do you think how to read the article ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438719/how-do-i-present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene

Comment: @tomojiro Don't worry, no anger, just trying to help a first time poster to improve the question to get more answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot present a viewController from within a SKScene as it is actually only being rendered on a SKView. You need a way to send a message to the viewController, which in turn will present the viewController. For this, you can use **delegation**.

Add the following protocol definition to your SKScene's .h file:

```
@protocol sceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)showShareScreen;
@end
```

And declare a delegate property in the interface:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <sceneDelegate> delegate;
```

Then, at the point where you want to present the share screen, instead of the line:

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Use this line:

```
[self.delegate showShareScreen];
```

Now, in your viewController's .h file, implement the protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <sceneDelegate>
```

And, in your .m file, add the following line before you present the scene:

```
scene.delegate = self;
```

Then add the following method there:

```
-(void)presentShareScreen
{

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
        composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"TestTweet from the Game !!"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

An alternate method would be to use **NSNotificationCenter**

Keep the `-presentShareScreen` method as described in the previous alternative.

Add the viewController as a listener to the notification in it's `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(presentShareScreen) name:@"showShareScreen" object:nil];
```

Then, in the scene at the point where you want to show this viewController, use this line:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showShareScreen" object:nil];

Comment: I am so glad to see your answer, thank you.                        But, I am not sure how to use this following line             scene.delegate = self;        Where should I use in .m file ? When I used it in  ViewController.m file, it didn't work. And it is saying,  Property 'delegate' not found on object of type "SKScene"

Comment: You need to add the protocol before the interface definition of your GameOverScene

Comment: I am so confused now... I should search SKScene and add the protocol to the SKScene's file. I added the protocol to the SKScene's subclass, like this "@interface MainScene : SKScene <sceneDelegate>  " I am so confused now, but I will do my best :)

Comment: Ummm... I replaced [self.delegate showShareScreen]; to my GameOverScene.m's the twitter method. But, my ViewController.m doesn't delegate the method(showShareScreen). It worked, but it doesn't delegate, because when I use breakpoint in the showShareScreen method, it didn't stop... May I ask the reason ??? By the way, to use   scene.delegate = self;  I made instance from GameOverScene's instance. It works for me, probably.

Comment: @tomojiro I have added a simpler and alternative method for this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much your advise. I realised that there is another instance of GameOverScene's instance, so I didn't delegate property. I instanced new viewController. Moreover, I delegated to viewController from GameOverScene.m . But other issue occurs, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568353/warning-attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-wit?noredirect=1#comment34353639_22568353        I am solving this issue now, anyway thank you so much, sir !!

Comment: @tomojiro Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.