# integrate facebook and twitter

Tags: ios, share, sprite-kit

in a SpriteKit game I want to integrate facebook and twitter. 
I tried:

```
            if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {


                SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
                [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"love luvlee"];

            }
```

but i can't present it using:

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

what could be the reason for that?

Comment: And why can't you present it that way? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteKit does not have the method `[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];`. Only view controllers can do that.

Your solution is to either get a reference to the view controller or add a method to the view controller that does the posting for you and you simply pass the desired values to.

Comment: how do i get such a reference?

Comment: @user3138007 - You can create a VC class property for the SKScene in question and pass the VC 'self' as you init your SKScene.

Comment: can somebody please post some sample code .. i am quite new to xcode and do not know how to do it ..

Comment: @user3138007 - That's a different question all together. I suggest you post a new question specifically related to this.

Comment: @user3138007 - I came across 2 links that might provide you with some useful help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421252/how-do-i-present-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene-with-social-framework

Comment: @user3138007 - and this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=10721