# How do you present a view controller in a SKScene?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to figure out how to use a share sheet for my SpriteKit game and when I try to present the view controller from my scene, it gives me an error.

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.shareButton {
        var tempMessage = "I just got \(score) on [insert app]"

        let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [tempMessage], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is in my GameOverScene. How exactly do you go about managing viewcontrollers in Swift because the answers I have seen were in OBJ-C.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "GameOverScene does not have a member named presentViewController"

Comment: the `self.presentViewController` has to be called from the ViewController containing the view of the `SKScene`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present another View Controller from SkScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756865/present-another-view-controller-from-skscene) and from the looks of it, several others too: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=view+controller+skscene+present

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I did some digging and found a solution that works.

Basically, I used NSNoticationCenter and set up the view controller in my GameViewController file as such.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
.
.
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showSocialNetworks", name: "showSocialNetworksID", object: nil)
}
```

and made the function to be called

```
func showSocialNetworks(){
    var tempMessage = "Insert your message to be shared on social network"

    let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [tempMessage], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now jump back to my GameOverScene, I set it up so when the user taps the Share Button, it performs the following code

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.shareButton {
             NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showSocialNetworksID",  object: nil)

}
```

This may not be the cleanest way to do it, but it works for me. Hope this helps!