# How to present view controller from SKScene?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3, viewcontroller

How to present view controller from `SKScene` in `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3`?
Someone know a simple way to present the view controller from `SKScene`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Present another View Controller from SkScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756865/present-another-view-controller-from-skscene)

Comment: I may have this completely wrong... but I think it's views that you present with a viewController, much like an SKView presents Scenes. So what you want... maybe, is to transfer control of SKView to a ViewController? I could be VERY wrong about this.

Comment: only view controllers can present other view controllers,  The idea is to somehow get a message to the view controller so that it can present the new view controller.  You can do this through NSNotification, or create a delegate

Comment: Code formatting, extra text removed

Comment: Store a reference to your view controller in your scene and use that to present the new view controller.