# setting SKScene delegate from viewcontroller, delegate not found

Tags: objective-c, delegates, sprite-kit, header-files

Trying to open a view controller from an SKScene.

Found https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072795/1686319 very helpful, but i get an error when trying to set the delegate from the view controller.

> No visible @interface for 'SKScene' declares the selector
>   'setDelegate:'

```
EABMyScene.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@protocol EABMySceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)doSomething;
@end

@interface EABMyScene : SKScene {

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <EABMySceneDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Any idea?

Update:

EABViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) openTweetSheet;
@end

@interface EABViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

EABViewController.m

```
#import "EABViewController.h"
#import "EABMyScene.h"

@implementation EABViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [EABMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [scene setDelegate:self];

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

-(void)openTweetSheet
{
    NSLog(@"Open Tweet Delegate Method");
}
```

EABMyScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface EABMyScene : SKScene {

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Error: No visible @interface for 'SKScene' declares the selector 'setDelegate:'

Comment: cast to (EABMyScene*)

Comment: If you are trying to implement the code in the link, you are defining the delegate in the wrong place. It should be in your view controller not your SKScene subclass.

Comment: casting the scene to EABMyScene didnt work. The delegate property in EABMyScene.h is still not found/accessible.

The delegate @property should be in the SKScene subclass i guess, so that i can set the viewcontroller as a delegate for my SKScene?

Looks like no property in the SKScene header file is accessible or found in a viewcontroller after importing SKScene header file.

Comment: I suggest you reread the answer in the link. The @protocol definition should be in a view controller's .h file not in EABMyScene.h.

Comment: I see it now, sorry my bad. Changed it, but the i still can not set/find/access the SKScenes delegate property from where the SKScene is initialized in my viewcontrollers viewDidLoad method

Comment: If you post your changes, I will try to find the issue.

Comment: I've updated/edited the question with my changes 0x141E

Comment: Change [scene setDelegate:self]; to [(EABMyScene *)scene setDelegate:self];

Comment: WARNING: don't use `delegate` keyword as a name for your property! It is reserved by iOS 8 SDK, your app will crash on iOS 8. Rename it to `mySceneDelegate` or something like this.

Comment: Worked like a charm 0x141E, thanks a lot. 
Post it as an answer so i can select it.

Thanks for the information Andrey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class SKScene does not have a property named delegate, so the statement

```
[scene setDelegate:self];
```

produced the compiler error. To fix this issue, cast scene to your SKScene subclass EABMyScene:

```
[(EABMyScene *)scene setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: It will have a delegate in 10.10 and 8.0 so be careful what you name it now.