# Cant set SKScene delegate to self ios8

Tags: ios, delegates, ios8, sprite-kit, skscene

So I go back to my view controller from my skscene using the following [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916702/go-back-to-view-controller-from-skscene) from a previous question I have asked. But now since ios8 I now get an error saying. Has anyone else dealt with this since the release of ios8 how did they fix it?

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TCAMyScene setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79485190'
```

Now from this answer [Delegate not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493302/setting-skscene-delegate-from-viewcontroller-delegate-not-found) I have tried changing

```
theScene.delegate = self;
```

to..

```
[(TCAMyScene *)theScene setDelegate:self];
```

but I still get the same error. 
This is the warning im getting..
[image]

Comment: Does TCAMyScene inherit from SKScene? And are you running this on an iOS 8 simulator/device? The delegate method is available only in iOS 8.0 onwards.

Comment: Well mixed behaviours in ios7 the app will crash with the error I gave about and iOS8 it won't crash on that delegate line but when it comes to calling [self.mySceneDelegate mySceneDidFinish:self]; from my scene to go back to the vc nothing happens.Sorry if the question was confusing I meant to say since the release of ios8 this issue happens @LearnCocos2D and im running from iOS 7 and 8 simulators

Comment: and yes TCAMyScene inherits from SKScene @LearnCocos2D

Comment: Did you add `@property (nonatomic, weak> id<TCAMySceneDelegate> delegate;` to the `@interface` of `TCAMyScene`? Also, `SKScene` class (and its subclasses) already has a `delegate` property. You should rename your `delegate` to something like `myDelegate`.

Comment: I have done both those things I have found that solution also in another answer but it didn't help @0x141E

Comment: If you changed `delegate` to `myDelegate`, the assignment statement should be `((TCAMyScene)theScene).myDelegate = self;` or `[(TCAMyScene)theScene setMyDelegate:self];`. Also, add `<TCAMySceneDelegate>` to your view controller's `.h` file if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thank you! You can go ahead and put this as the answer ((TCAMyScene *)theScene).mySceneDelegate = self; after changing the name i never changed the assignment statement! ill mark it as correct! @0x141E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment statement should be

```
    ((TCAMyScene)theScene).myDelegate = self;
```

or

```
    [(TCAMyScene)theScene setMyDelegate:self];
```

if you changed the `delegate` to `myDelegate`,