# Nil modal viewcontroller object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

From my gameScene, I am using it to disconnect. But in essence, it is to move viewController.

**GameScene**

```
@implementation

gameController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];

-(void)disconnect {       
    [gameController disconnectAction];
}

@interface

GameViewController *gameController;
```

**GameViewController**

```
@interface

#import "ConnectionsViewController.h"

-(void)disconnectAction;

@implementation

-(void)disconnectAction {
    ConnectionsViewController *game = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConnectionsViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:game animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, this returns the error of `trying to modal a nil viewcontroller`. And yes, the storyboard ID is correct. I have also tried

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

However, this returns a nil storyboard exception.

Comment: Is `self.storyboard` nil?

Comment: @Larme that's right, and it's being ran from the viewController, which has that viewController imported >:|

Comment: How did you show `GameViewController`?

Comment: @Larme the scene is presented in GameViewController i.e `[skView presentScene:scene];`

Comment: @Larme also GameViewController was presented from my lobbyController in the same way that it is trying to present a different viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Use below think...may be help you..

```
-(void)disconnectAction {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ConnectionsViewController" sender:nil];
}

Make sure that you have to set view controller relationship in your storyboard.
```

Comment: When you say make sure I've set a relationship, does that simply mean a storyboard ID?

Comment: Chadasama I get a has no segue with identifier error.

Comment: all my other viewcontrollers modal perfectly with the code I've provided. However, when trying to do it whilst an skscene is present, i've ran into this problem.

Comment: Also, on-top of that. After the performSegue method it runs the GameViewController viewDidLoad method. Rather than moving controller. This is such a weird complex.

Comment: This is very simple you just have to put this code and set relationship in your story board..this will work...what exactly problem you have to fetch.. ConnectionsViewController is only class..without view?

Comment: ConnectionsViewController is a ViewController with a view. When you say set a relationship, can you elaborate?

Comment: maybe no problems with the code, however maybe a problem with our communication.. You're saying set a relationship in my storyboard. However, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: mean that from one viewcontrollrt press cntrl+click and drag line to another view controller(which you have to pop)

Comment: then I run into a no anchor error as well as a viewcontroller identifier error.

Answer (score 0):

I was required to setup a @protocol & delegate for the method to run for moving the viewcontroller.

[How do I present a UIViewController from SKScene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438719/how-do-i-present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene/20072795#20072795)

This helped greatly.